# Why does my pointer for an unsigned long array increment by 8 bytes instead of four?

Tags: c, arrays, long-integer, sizeof

I have an array of unsigned long that I expect to be 4 bytes per array element (32 bits), like this:

```
unsigned long giantbuffer[1024];
```

However, when I Print out the address of my array elements I get:

```
printf("%X\n", &giantbuffer[0]);  --> gives ab8470

printf("%X\n", &giantbuffer[1]);  --> gives ab8478
```

also,

```
sizeof(giantbuffer) gives 8192, and sizeof(giantbuffer[0]) gives 8.
```

That is eight bytes per array element!  Is this something that is dependent on system architecture or something?  I am new to C, so maybe this is an obvious thing?  This wreaks havoc with my pointer arithmetic.  I am using "ch" to do some interpreter command-line style checking of my syntax, etc.  Maybe this is a problem with that program?

Comment: Why do you expect `long` to be 4 bytes long? Any sensible 64-bit architecture/implementation I know of defines `long` as a 64-bit type. (Yes, Win64 does not count as a sensible implementation.)

Comment: If you want an integer of a specific size, use stdint.h

Answer (score 4):

Because on your environment, the sizeof `unsigned long` is 8 bytes. Pointer arithmetic depends on the type of object being pointed to:

```
int i = 10;
int *p_i  = &i;
```

Incrementing `p_i` by 1 - increases the pointer with `sizeof(int)` bytes.

```
char c = 10;
char *p_c  = &i;
```

Incrementing `p_c` by 1 - increases the pointer with `sizeof(char)` bytes, and so on.

> Is this something that is dependent on system architecture or something?

Yes. It also depends on your Compiler and also if the architecture is 32 / 64 bit.

Comment: I think also add about how pointer's math  works

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Deducing from the question, I think OP knows how pointer arithmetic works. He's just a victim of wrong assumptions about the size of data types.

Comment: @H2CO3 Hmm correct!!.. I read title and first two codes piece only

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - Thanks, just for good to know information added your point.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a specific amount of bytes for a datatype, don't use types like `unsigned long`.  Instead, check out something like the [`stdint` header](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdint.h).

Instead of:

```
unsigned long myvar = 0;
unsigned long mybuf[100];
```

you'd do:

```
uint32_t myvar = 0;
uint32_t mybuf[100];
```

and you'll get a 32-bit value wherever you go.

Clarification:
    Based on your system architecture, `uint32_t` gets `typedef`'ed to `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`. This is typically handled by use of preprocessor macros as below:

```
#ifdef __x86_64__
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
#else
typedef unsigned long uint32_t;
#endif
```